# I want to send the servlet in angularjs

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I want to send the ImageFile(MultipartFile) servlet using the angularjs.
However,it will not be able to get in @RequestParam Annotation spring.

jsp

```
<form method="POST" id="image-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="imageFile" name="imageFile" accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png" />
    <div id="search-button">
        <input type="button" ng-click="searchCtrl.imageSearch();">
    </div>
</form>
```

javascript

```
var $form;
var formData = new FormData();

$form = $("#image-form");
formData.append("imageFile", $form[0]);

request = $http({
    method : 'post',
    url : "/addImage",
    data : data,
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : undefined
    },
    transformRequest : null
});

return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
```

java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<SearchImageRequestModel> logo_upload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    Model model, @PathVariable("service_id") String serviceId, @RequestParam(value = "imageFile") MultipartFile file)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
...
```

Will you not be able to get an MultipartFile in the @RequestParam annotation.
Please kindly advise.

Comment: Are you trying to upload a file? What you mean bt "..send the servlet in angularjs"?

Comment: Thank you answer.
Also, Sorry reply late.

I wanted to upload a file from js to the servlet.
But In fact I didn't get the file in js.
Like writing was bad, I take the file Once you have this for writing.
$('#image-form').prop('files')[0].name;
Thank you.